# RadioButton Pointed over background color not working in dark mode

Tags: xaml, radio-button, uwp-xaml, winui

This gif shows that the background of the ellipse does not change color with the pointed over event (WinUi2 Xaml Controls Gallery)

[image: This gif shows that the background of the ellipse does not change color with the pointed over event]

---

The control behaves correctly in Xaml Controls Gallery WinUI 3 (see below):

[image: The control behaves correctly in Xaml Controls Gallery WinUI 3]

I tried modifying the Theme resources to apply a fix for the dark mode, using the testing the following resources:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseStrokePointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseFillPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedStrokePointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonOuterEllipseCheckedFillPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphFillPointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource RadioButtonCheckGlyphStrokePointerOver}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
```

However, I was unable to find the correct one for this fix. I need to modify a more obscure resource, but I was unable to find the correct one.

[image]

I tried modifying the theme resources, testing each one in order to see if I achieved the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the value for **OuterEllipse**.

Like this:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Yellow" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

To show the difference, I change the color to Yellow and Red. The following image is what it looks like after changing its color:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Roy Li! The help is much appreciated! Have a great weekend!